# Google Sheets calendar script is timing out

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-apps-script-triggers

```
function onEdit(e) {   
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  if(sheet.getName() != "Sheet2")
  {
    return;
  }

  var lastColoum = sheet.getLastColumn();

  for( A=1 ; A<=lastColoum ; A++) {//A <=lastcoloum
    var cell = sheet.getRange (3, A);
    var cellB = sheet.getRange (4, A);
    var status = cell.getValues();  
    if (status == "Mon" || status == "Tue" || status == "Wed"|| status == "Thu"|| status == "Fri") {
      sheet.unhideColumn(cell)
      for( A=1 ; A<=lastColoum ; A++) {//A <=lastcoloum
        var cell = sheet.getRange (3, A);
        var cellB = sheet.getRange (4, A);
        var status = cell.getValues();  
        if (status == "Sun" || status == "Sat" || cellB.isBlank()) {
          sheet.hideColumn(cell);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome. Please describe what your code does, include the textual error message, and add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your logic is, if a column is hidden, you can't add data to row 4. I would remove the "isBlank()" check, otherwise, you have to manually unhide a hidden column in order to add data to it (unless doing so with code I suppose). 
I did get the below to work based on what I think you are trying to do.

```
  function onEdit() {   
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var lastColoum = sheet.getDataRange().getLastColumn();

  for(var A=1; A<lastColoum +1; A++) { 
    var cell = sheet.getRange (3, A);
    var col = sheet.getRange(cell.getA1Notation()); //this style is used in hide/unhide as a range
    var status = cell.getValue();
    switch (status) { //instead of multiple If statements
      case "Mon":
      case "Tue":
      case "Wed":
      case "Thu":
      case "Fri":
          if (cell.offset(1, 0).isBlank()){ //use cell.offset(rowOffset, columnOffset) instead of making another call to the sheet.
                                            //if the row below the status is blank, hide column
          sheet.hideColumn(col);
          break;
          } else {
          sheet.unhideColumn(col);  //this will never get fired unless you are
                                    //adding data via some other means
          break;
          }

      case "Sat":                         //Sat, Sun (always hidden)
      case "Sun":
          sheet.hideColumn(col);
          break;
      }
    }
}
```